# How can I split my multi-part question into several questions?

Tags: discussion

It was suggested that [this question of mine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98626/how-can-i-make-hack-and-slash-less-mandatory-and-more-interesting) be split into multiple questions. I agree with this suggestion and apologize for the burden this now places on the community.

The problem is, it has two sizable answers already, so closing/deleting it and re-creating it in two or three questions might not be a great option. So, at the risk of great irony, I will ask two questions here:

1. How do I retain the answers and split this question into multiple questions?
2. Should it be two or three questions?

Update: I've since split it into a second question addressing only the formerly third part of the original question, visible here: [How can I describe Hack-and-Slash effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98761/how-can-i-describe-hack-and-slash-effects)

Answer (score 3):

OK, I placed the question on hold so that we can figure this out before it gets more answers.

There's only 2 answers so far so if either author is "with us" it should be easy to split the Q and have them migrate their answer over.  With any question that gets answers when it's too broad, question changes may require some tuning to the existing answers; that's OK.

So I'd say ask a second Q with the part of the Q that seems less addressed in the current answers and invite those authors to edit and repost their "other parts" on the new Q.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll do so today.

Comment: ...or maybe tomorrow. Sorry for the delay everyone.

Comment: Done. If you find it acceptable now, could you release the original question from its hold?

Answer (score 2):

### How to split your question:

[Edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/98626/edit) your first question down to include only one of the questions it currently includes, then [ask](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) the now-removed separate question as a new question.

### What should I do about existing answers?

While not required, it's polite to leave a comment on existing answers saying something like "I've edited my question; you may want to revise this answer accordingly."  This is mostly important so the answerer gets a notification and knows to take a look.

### Should it be 2 or 3 questions?

I'd say you'd be fine with 2.  The things you've listed as questions 1 and 2 seem to me to be a "How do I do X, or if I can't what would be a good alternative" pair, which is fine and not too broad (and the second part wouldn't make much sense without the first as context).  I'd separate the part you have listed as question 3 and ask it separately.

Comment: Thanks, knowing to just do 2 questions is valuable advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be three questions.  There's no real downside to splitting it all the way, and I disagree that the questions are related enough to leave 1 and 2 together.