# Why doesn't this site allow opinion-based side questions?

Tags: support, questions, on-topic, policy, multiple-questions-per-post

I have asked several questions which contain side questions. For example, in [a question regarding familiars using magic items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138348/can-pact-of-the-chain-warlocks-familiars-particularly-imps-and-sprites-attune), I asked

> What would be the best magic item(s) to give an imp (for maximum chaos)?

as part of my original question, and was rebuffed for this.

Every time I've included similar things people have told me I can't do that. And I imagine that it would be very enjoyable for someone to read though the magic items and imagine the sort of crazy things imps could do with them. I think it would make answering the question entertaining.

I understand that this site is a rules site. But I want to include goofy side things that aren't essential to the question, because that should make the questions more fun to answer and the answers more entertaining to read. And I really don't see any reason to not include them.

So please explain the reasoning behind this rule.

Comment: Please note that I am not attacking the rules, I would simply like them explained.

Comment: Related: [What do I do with a question that contains multiple questions in its body and/or title?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6426/33569), [How can I split my multi-part question into several questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7032/33569), [Should I ask one question or several?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4924/33569), [Are “bonus question” allowed?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8056/33569), [1 post - 1 question , is it a rule or a guideline or what?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6453/33569)

Comment: Please note even with this you are asking two different questions - a) why don't we allow multi-part questions and b) why don't we allow brainstorming questions. The answers to those are different, and all the above links should explain a) quite well.

Comment: Both of these restrictions are common across all SE sites - here's why not to brainstorm, from the EE SE. https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/428/brainstorming-in-the-form-of-a-question

Answer (score 26):

### Not just rules

Just to get that misconception out of the way first: this isn’t a rules site. We handle many types of questions, so long as they can, in theory, have a “best” answer. We allow answers based on **facts** *or* based on **experience** with a working solution. Or both.

That lets us handle a much wider variety of questions than just rules questions. Check out our [group-dynamics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-dynamics) tag sometime for an example of one type.

### One question per post is non-negotiable

We only do one question per post. That’s required so that the topic of each page is *one* topic. This is required so that

- our database is well organized and searchable
- no questions are hidden from searching and sorting inside other questions
- answers are all competing to answer the same question (instead of some answering one part and some answering a differing thing)
- answers are all on the same topic, so they can be compared “apples to apples” and scored on an even playing field

There’s also a benefit for the asker: your one question gets the full attention of everyone on that page.

The alpha and omega of any site rule or feature is how it supports the creation of a well-sorted database of clear questions, each with a well-sorted list of competing solutions.

The one question per post rule is a key site rule supporting our database project. It’s why we have quality answers to provide, which is why you and others come here at all.

#### The site provides multiple posts instead

The site welcomes multiple questions though: we are encouraged to make multiple posts when we have multiple questions.

So instead of jamming multiple discrete questions into one post, we get to post them as multiple separate question posts. Each question gets its own votes, and the full attention of any answerers who are reading it, without distractions from “bonus” questions or fun side things. The end results are better for the asker, and make for a more orderly, easier to read site.

Of course, each separate question post must be on-topic for the site; on the plus side, posting them separately makes it much clearer, faster, which questions are on topic and which off.

### We hate fun

Well, not really, but we’re on a mission here. We’re *already* enjoying asking and answering questions, and wouldn’t be here if we didn’t.

Adding different ideas of “fun” than that just interferes with the mission that is the point of using the site, and which we’re already enjoying just fine.

The reason you get quality answers here is because we’re focused on providing *only* that.

### No chaos, thanks

Adding “fun” side pieces to questions just invites people to go off in different directions instead of focusing on the topic of the question. We don’t want that, and have rules to prevent it.

If you want to have discussions that involve that sort of fun, that’s fine! It’s a good kind of fun. **Just not here**, please: it’s not what the site was created to do, so we’re going to stop people who try.

There are already [literal *piles* of RPG sites for fun discussions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). Use one of those instead when you want a fun chat.

Comment: I feel this answer would be improved by adding to the "one question, one post" section a reminder that posting many, good questions is encouraged.

Comment: @nitsua60 Good catch.

Answer (score 9):

I saw your original post. It seemed easy enough, but there were a couple of problems as a question for this format of question/answer site, which has such a heavy focus on creating a big history of answered questions for people to search.

1. The one-question-one-answer format means that if someone has a question like "can imps attune?", they can easily find the question and the top answer TO THAT QUESTION. If there's a question and a side question like "best familiar to attune with belt of dwarvenkind?", the top answer might be the best answer to the Imp attunement, and a bad answer to belt of dwarvenkind.
2. This site seems more focused on explaining mechanics, getting advice for basic game mechanics, and answering technical questions. Brainstorming insane combinations of familiars and items is a fun topic, but it's better suited for forums or among friends.

Comment: I feel this answer would be improved by adding to the "one-question-one-answer" point a reminder that posting many, good questions is encouraged.